# How to get rid of sharp edges

Tags: edges

[image]

I tried smoothing it out, but it still there. How do i get rid of it.

Comment: Are you using subsurf?

Comment: please share this part of your object so that we understand its topology: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Generally its not just a case of adding a subsurface modifier it depends on the topology and what you are trying to achieve. By adding a subsurface modifier to the above it will round the edge completely as there is not control loop to stop it. A bevel modifier with shade smooth possibly or work on the topology.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is no edge separation in that part just press 'smooth' button in tools panel.

[image]

If your surface is flat, your model would be cleaner if you check that in that broken part, all of the vertices are placed in the same plane.